# Is there a difference between the github webhook dependabot.alert.number and the github api dependabot.number

Tags: github-api, github-webhook

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm currently working on a project that involves pulling data from the GitHub API and reconciling it with data obtained via the GitHub Webhook API, focusing specifically on Dependabot alerts. I'm curious to know if the dependabot.alert.number received through the webhook is equivalent to the dependabot.number retrieved when pulling data from the API using the following endpoint:

`https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/dependabot/alerts`

If they aren't equivalent, is there a specific way to obtain the alert number from the API side when processing webhooks, and perhaps I've overlooked it?

Your insights and expertise would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you, and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to a GitHub CSM and got the following answer:

> the alert number in the webhook event is the same as the dependabot number you get from that API endpoint, so mapping them to each other using that should work.

Hope that helps anyone else who was confused by this too!